# How can I extract a column's (called say "X") any cell value from a text file with multiple columns using Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, git-bash

I have a huge file with 100 columns.
I am concerned with one column called 'Location'. I know for a fact that all rows of this column are same in value. I need to get that value through **Bash**.
Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: What's the exact format of the file? Likely you can use `awk`, but if this is (for example) a CSV file that allows quoted commas in a field, you're going to want to use a language that has a proper CSV parser.

Comment: please add a small sample of the file (eg, with 4-6 columns and rows), the code you've attempted so far, the (wrong) output you're getting, and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If the column is always in the same location relative to other columns (say 10th) you could use
`cut -d" " -f10`
In this case you're assuming there's one whitespace between each column, you could change the delimiter to whatever separates between the columns.